# error when reading from list box

Tags: c#, .net, listboxitem

Im trying to find a string in a list box. if its found to show a message box and if not it to throw a different message box. but im getting a error on the false part. please help.

```
{    
    string myString = metroTextBox1.Text;//username
    // Search starting from index -1:
    int index = listBox1.FindString(myString, -1);//username

    if (index != -1)
    {
        listBox1.SetSelected(index, true);//username
        MessageBox.Show("ok");
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.SetSelected(index, false);//username
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }

}
```

Comment: why you are trying to access index when it is set to -1 in else part `listBox1.SetSelected(index, false);`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set an item to selected in your listbox, but the index you're passing in is -1. If you don't find that string in the list box, then you can't set any item to false. You could do something else, such as loop through all the available items and set them to false, but it depends on what you want to happen in that instance where the string you're looking for isn't found. You may just want to do nothing in that else clause TBH.

```
if (index != -1)
{
    listBox1.SetSelected(index, true);//username
    MessageBox.Show("ok");
}
else
{
    listBox1.SetSelected(index, false);//username    // Index == -1 here. This will FAIL.
    MessageBox.Show("error");
}
```